# C/C++ Plugin for Intellij-Idea Community edition

Tags: c++, c, intellij-idea, clion

I'm using:
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-183.5912.21, built on February 26, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b28 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

I want to use C/C++ code. I know that there is a separate IDE 'CLion' available for this, but is it possible to integrate C/C++ in this community edition of Intellij only? I don't want to have any seperate IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no C/C++ support for IntelliJ IDEA Community and Ultimate at the moment.

[Here is the related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4141). Even when implemented, it will be probably available only in the Ultimate version.

Comment: This is so very annoying, since it works perfectly in AndroidStudio...